# How do I get the browser to open the pdf in a new tab instead of just downloading it?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a Download button and a View button. The file is downloaded via MVC controller function returning FileResult.

The controller function looks like this:

```
    public FileResult DownloadStatement(Guid statementID) {
        StatementFileModel statementFile = BL.GetStatementByID(statementID);
        byte[] fileBytes = statementFile.FileData;
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + statementFile.FileName);
        Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
        return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf");
    }
```

The following works great for downloading the PDF immediately without opening it in the browser:

```
window.location.href = "/DownloadStatement?statementID=" + statementID;
```

I'm having trouble with the View button though. I tried the following but it also just downloads the PDF without opening it in the browswer:

```
window.open("/DownloadStatement?statementID=" + statementID, '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Content-Disposition: attachment` header tells the browser to download the file. Don't send that header value (`attachment`) when the "View" button is clicked, and the browser should display the PDF rather than downloading it.

Omitting the header entirely, or sending `Content-Disposition: inline`, should suffice.

Comment: doesn't open in a new tab as requested though

Answer (score 1):

Use
`header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + statementFile.FileName)` for download;
use
`header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + statementFile.FileName);` to open it in Browser:

Comment: doesn't open in a new tab as requested though